# C++ how can I define classes at runtime?

Tags: c++, boost

The idea is to create object at runtime in C++.

The input for this creation is going to be a json file. For example

```
{
  "pi": 3.141,
  "happy": true,
  "name": "Niels",
  "nothing": null,
  "answer": {
    "everything": 42
  },
  "list": [1, 0, 2],
  "object": {
    "currency": "USD",
    "value": 42.99
  }
}
```

What are the options to do this in  C++? Can boost help on this?

Comment: You can't create classes at runtime.

Comment: So you want to create classes or objects at runtime ? One is easy (objects), the other is AFAIK impossible (classes). If you want to parse JSON with boost, you can use [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/property_tree.html)

Comment: It is impossible to actually create new classes, but your question did remind me of an interesting talk by Sean Parent, [Runtime Polymorphism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGcVXgEVMJg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do (define classes at runtime) that in standard C++, because a class has some code associated to it (at least, implicit constructors and destructors, and very often member functions, and very often has some [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), generated by the compiler, pointing to code).

Your JSON parsing library (e.g. [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp)) will provide a type representing arbitrary JSON objects (in braces).

On some [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), you could load a [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) (containing code) at runtime; on Linux and POSIX use [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) but beware of [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) (see [C++ dlopen Mini-HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/)). The plugin is a shared object that you need to compile specifically as [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code). Several framework libraries ([Qt](http://qt.io/), [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/), [Boost DLL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_dll.html) ...) provide common abstractions to load plugins, ...

You could even (I did that in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), on Linux) generate some C++ code on the fly at runtime in some temporary file, compile that temporary file into some temporary plugin, and load that plugin .... all this in the same [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)).

Comment: I'm gonna add relevant part of my answer as a FWIW-comment: "You can create a type which values are "dynamic enough" to mimic something similar, like holding/representing multiple types. This is [what boost does](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/property_tree/parsers.html#property_tree.parsers.json_parser)." This approach would be alternative to injecting a "compiled type". One could also explore how C# implements generic types, but I guess they rely on IL, but there is a support for dynamically created type.

Comment: @lik32: This is what [Michael Roy's answer](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) suggests. However, the OP is *parsing* JSON, and any JSON parser needs to represent JSON objects (or be event based)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, or something close to this (i'm simplifying):

```
class VariableClass
{
private:
   typedef map<string, boost::any> MembersMap;

   string objectType;  // a label, defined at parsing... 
                       // could be an ID, but then you'd already know 
                       // the members to expect, and could use a 'regular' class.
   MembersMap members;

... etc...
   boost::any& operator [](const std:string& s) ( return members[s]; }
};
```

This is oversimplified, but should do what you want.  You may want to replace boost::any with std::variant, or a custom specialized template class holding the types you want, which could also be determined at runtime from the json.

[edit] I've added a variable 'objectType'.

Comment: You've defined a class which contains a map, and provides a function to retrieve things from the map. How is this any better than just using a map?

Comment: This class could of course provide more functionality as needed...  We have no idea what the OP really wants to do with the data.  He could also add a label to the class.  Which I'll add now, to clarify.